# Transfer Domain name from one hosting to another

Tags: web-hosting, domain-transfer

Good day!

When I was just in college, I created my very own website, bought a domain name from namecheap then hosted it to my friends server(sentora). Now that I have graduated, I have created my very own server(try) and wanted to host my very own website using Centos. As a newbie, how do I transfer my domain name from my friend's hosting to my own hosting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but we already have a vast amount of questions and answers regarding transferring domains. It differs from domain extension to registrar, so you if you can't find the answer in the [305 similar questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=transfer+domain+is%3Aquestion) asked on Pro Webmasters then you should contact both registrars, in fact, it's better you contact them first in any case as they will give you step by step instructions, while the answers on here will be generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a complete backup of your domain from Sentora and extract it to new server.

But it needs some operations move website from hosting package to own server like, name server registration, ip blacklist control, reverse dns register, vs...

Did you do any of them above?

Comment: Yes sr. Did everything and it worked like a charm. However, I am not able to create a new database in my panel. It always prompts me #1044 access denied for user